# Android и масштабирование элементов

Tags: java, android, listview, интерфейс, android-layout

Есть ли способ пропорционального масштабирования элементов интерфейса? Поясню на примере: если при запуске на экране 100х200 помещаются 5 пунктов ListView, то при запуске на экране 200х400 помещались все те же 5, а размеры элементов, включая и размеры шрифтов, увеличивались пропорционально.

Answer (score 2):

1. Заведите эталонные размеры в виде констант
2. При запуске на к-л девайсе получайте его размеры и вычисляйте коэффициент отличия полученных размеров от эталонных.
3. В `getView` адаптера списка назначайте высоту элементов равной `эталон * коэффициент`. То же делайте для шрифтов etc.

Answer (score 0):

Параметр  `android:layout_weight`

Например:

```
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_opis"
                    android:layout_width="164dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text_opis"
                    android:text="@string/button2"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="172dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/button3"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, android:layout_weight не масштабирует, он просто перераспределяет ширину элементов в соответствии с их weight-коэффициентами